# Chrome: Is the order of document.cookie guaranteed?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, standards

```
document.cookie='foobar'
```

.followed by:

```
console.log(document.cookie.indexOf('foobar'))
```

.always gives me `0` when tested on Chromes.

Is the order guaranteed (by anything) for Chrome?

<sup>(Also might be interested in Ecmascript /Firefox /etc.)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

No, the order is not guaranteed.

The `document.cookie` is an accessor property with native setter and getter functions. If you set a value, a single cookie will be added/updated. If you get the value, a semicolon-delimited list of all the cookies will be returned.

The order in which the list will be returned (as far as I could find) is undefined behavior. [The definition of `document.cookie`](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-8747038) from the "Document Object Model (DOM) Level 2 HTML Specification" only states that:

> When this attribute is read, all cookies are returned as a single string, with each cookie's name-value pair concatenated into a list of name-value pairs, each list item being separated by a ';' (semicolon).

In general (tested on Chrome/Firefox/Edge) it seems that cookies that are set first using the `document.cookie`, are returned first. So in your case, if you have set another cookie before you set "foobar", then "foobar" wont be at string index 0.

```
document.cookie='anothercookie=anothercookie';
document.cookie='foobar=foobar';

console.log('cookie', document.cookie); // cookie anothercookie=anothercookie; foobar=foobar
console.log('index', document.cookie.indexOf('foobar')); // index 29
```

Interestingly, it seems that cookies that are set using the `set-cookie` header are placed after the cookies that are set using the `document.cookie`, eventhough they are set first. A fiddle can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/y357pc0x/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you may consider `document.cookie` as some kind of array. But `document.cookie` is just a `string`.

`'foobar'.indexOf('foobar')` returns `0` because `foobar` has been found at index 0.

Comment: Yepp.. q is if it is guaranteed to do so.